# Auto-updating WFST store with GeoExt/OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, wfs-t

I built an WFS-T with a grid panel (Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel) to edit features' attributes. Now, I want the feature store (GeoExt.data.FeatureStore) to reload/update automatically so that other users see changes committed immediately without reloading the whole webmap.

How do I:

1. Attach such an "update store" function either to my "save"-button or to my store's "afteredit"-listener?
2. Have the whole store updated continuously in an automatic way?

Answer (score 3):

Solved! 
..by using refresh Strategy:

1.Intitalize:
`var refreshStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh();`

2.Apply strategy to WFS-Layer:
`var POIs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Schneeampel", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), saveStrategy, refreshStrategy],
                projection: WGS84,
                // empty style map, will be populated in setLayerStyles
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({...`

3.Register event "refresh" in combination with event "save" in Save-Button-section:
`saveStrategy.events.register("success", null, function(){refreshStrategy.refresh()})`