# How to make WFS-T layer grid panel with Geoext

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext

I am using geoext,openlayers and geoserver. I am using WFSCapabilitiesStore to make the grid panel. I want to this grid panel WFS-T layer so that on each layer I can draw and edit feature after adding these layer to tree panel. My store object for for grid panel is this:

```
store = new GeoExt.data.WFSCapabilitiesStore({
         url: "http://mindcrewgis.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities",
         protocolOptions: {version: "1.0.0"},
          layerOptions: {
                         visibility: false,
                          displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
                           strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ratio: 1}),saveStrategy ],
                           projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                          geometryName: "geom",
                          srs: 'EPSG:4326',
          }

    });
     // load the store with records derived from the doc at the above url   
    store.load();
```

The above store object is displaying properly the grid as well as all layers, but after adding the layer to the tree panel and I draw feature on layer. The feature is not saved. Can anybody help me to that? how can i make a grid panel and layer to editable feaure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this helps http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48425/how-to-auto-update-wfst-store-with-geoext-openlayers